# Python: pip in venv doesn't install packages in the venv. It install packages in the default location instead. What could be wrong?

Tags: python

Creation of venv with python3 is ok.
However, when I run pip install requests in the venv, the package has been installed in the normal python site-package outside of the venv.framework folder. The pip doesn't install package in the venv.

I've installed python3 from brew.
I've installed python3.9 and python3.10, which are downloaded from the python homepage.

Outside of the venv, the 'which' command looks like this.
which python

> /usr/local/bin/python
> which python3
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
> which python3.9
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
> which python3.10
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10
> which pip
> pip: aliased to /usr/local/bin/pip3
> which pip3
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip3
> which pip3.9
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip3.9
> which pip3.10
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pip3.10
> echo $PATH
> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Inside of the venv:
which python

> /....../venv_test/venv/bin/python.
> which python3
> /....../venv_test/venv/bin/python3
> which python3.9
> /....../venv_test/venv/bin/python3.9
> which python3.10
> /....../venv_test/venv/bin/python
> which pip
> pip: aliased to /usr/local/bin/pip3
> which pip3
> /....../venv_test/venv/bin/pip3
> which pip3.9
> /....../venv_test/venv/bin/pip3.9
> which pip3.10
> /....../venv_test/venv/bin/pip3.10
> echo $PATH
> /....../venv_test/venv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Please help.

Comment: when you say "inside of the venv" do you mean you cd inside of the folder ?

Comment: Are you activating your virtual environment? Please provide the code you used.

Comment: when I say "inside of the venv", it means I did "source venv/bin/activate".

Comment: I created my venv with "python3 -m venv venv".